# Using PsEXEC via SQL Server agent job

Tags: sql-server, server, agent, psexec

I have a need to add a step (a batch file that needs to run on the application server) once my backup from db server is complete. I am thinking of using the PsEXEC. For whatever reason the command I am testing via the query window executes the batch file at the app server just fine but when I add the same command as step in SQL server agent job it is giving me the error "The process could not be created for step 1 of job 0x318474904D93B54A81BA8B1AEE891A13 (reason: The system cannot find the file specified).  The step failed."

Here is the command line running just fine from the query window

EXEC XP_CMDShell 'psexec -accepteula -u domain\user -p psswordhere \appserverip -s -d cmd.exe /c "F:\MovefFilesTest\TheJob\MoveTest.bat"'

FYI: domain\user is local admin on both servers and the sql service and agent are running under this account. It is also a sysadmin on the sql server itself.
Your help is appreciated. 
Also F:\ is a local drive on the app server. I am puzzled why it is working on the query window but not when added as agent job

Comment: If `F:` happens to be a mapped drive, you don't have mapped drives using psexec.

Comment: Why not use the built-in and fully-supported Powershell Remoting https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/running-remote-commands?view=powershell-6 instead of the unsupported PSEXEC tool?

Comment: F:\  is a local drive on the app server. I am puzzled whey it is working on the query window but not when added as agent job